# How to compare an item against others, that's compatible with string-equal?

Tags: string, symbols, equality

When comparing the `last-command` against multiple possible strings, it doesn't seem possible to use the member function.

Is there a way to simplify this using something like member?

```lisp
(when
  (or
    (string-equal last-command 'foo)
    (string-equal last-command 'bar)
    (string-equal last-command 'bob)
    (string-equal last-command 'baz))
  (do-something))
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```lisp
(when (member last-command (list 'foo 'bar 'bob 'baz))
  (do-something))
```

Comment: What you're showing here is not strings, but symbols. The only reason this works with `string-equal` is because it converts symbols to strings first.

Comment: Please don't change the question. If you have a new question, pose that separately.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by *"it didn't work"*. It works for me. I'm guessing that when you tried to test this `last-command` changed in the meantime, so it didn't match any of the symbols you expected.

Comment: I'm setting `this-command`, later comparing with `last-command`, using using `string-equal` succeeds, where as `member` does't.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're setting one to a string and the other to a symbol, the only scenario where `string-equal` behaves differently from `equal`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, for me.

```lisp
(when (member last-command (list 'foo 'bar 'bob 'baz)) (do-something))
```

First, `last-command` is typically a symbol, not a string.  There is no reason to use `string-equal` for two symbols.  It works, but it is slower - it just converts the symbols to strings and then compares those strings.

The best way to compare two symbols is with `eq`.  `eq` compares two Lisp objects, i.e., they must be the same object to return non-`nil`.  For a list, `memq` tests membership using `eq`.

Second, even if the things to compare were strings, `member` uses the test `equal`, which uses `string-equal` for string comparison.

If the question is really about `last-command`, and not about comparing symbols or strings, then be aware that `last-command` doesn't always return a symbol - see `C-h v last-command`.

> The last command executed.
>   Normally a symbol with a function definition, but can be whatever was found
>   in the keymap, or whatever the variable `this-command' was set to by that
>   command.

All the more reason to test with `member`, which uses `equal`.

(Also, you can just write `'(foo bar bob baz)` instead of `(list 'foo 'bar 'bob 'baz)`. But this is unimportant.)

Comment: What would be a better way to compare two symbols?

Comment: That is already in the answer, `eq` is sufficient for this and used by `memq`.

Comment: Note that `member` works when all values are strings too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually intend comparing strings, many `cl-lib` functions support a `:test` keyword argument to specify the comparison function:

```
(cl-member "foo" '(foo bar baz) :test 'string-equal)
```